# what we call this sign => in PHP array?

Tags: php

what do we call this sign `=>` in PHP array? example: like this is (`<=` less than equal to) this is (`>=` greater than equal to).

What is the right name for `=>` in PHP?

Comment: Rajendra - It would probably help if you showed an example of what you're talking about. But again, I very much doubt it has a specific name. Also, do you really mean to ask what it's **called**? Or did you want to know what it **means**?

Comment: T.J. thanks for your ans i know what it sign means and what it does but, i curious to know what it called generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally it appears to be called a `T_DOUBLE_ARROW`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: Which, if you ask me, sounds slightly confusing… I'd call `>>` a "double arrow", but that's not the first thing that comes to mind for `=>`…

Comment: :-) I'm guessing the "double" is for the `=` (vs. `-`), though "fat" and "thin" are the terms I usually hear...

Answer (score 4):

Colloquially I believe it's often called a fat comma or double arrow, but I still prefer to call it a fat arrow, even though the official token is called `T_DOUBLE_ARROW`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_comma#PHP

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Noted - but I think the deceze answered the technically correct term and I was trying to cover what that might be called when speaking to a fried/collague/recruiter - not really what is techically correct :)

Comment: The PHP section of that page supports your answer well.